# Split sentences with new line as delimiter using Java (1.7) Matcher

Tags: java, regex

I have a long sentence with embedded new lines or carriage returns that I want to split into separate sentences. An example such as:
`This is a new line=?xxx\n What's \n up` should produce `This is a new line=?xxx` `What's` and `up`

I do not want to use `String.split("\n")` but instead something like:

```
String x = "  This is a new line=?xxx\n Whats' \n up";
// This is not correct
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*[\r\n]+|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
while (m.find()) {
      System.out.printline(m.group(1));
}
```

The above code produces:

```
   This is a new line=?xxx
   What's
```

What's wrong with my regex?

Comment: It can't find anything after the last \n. So m.find() returns false.

Comment: `I do not want to use String.split("\n")` Can you clarify why?

Comment: Why not use just `.+` for matching *lines*?

Comment: I am applying the regex to a stream. Performance of String.split is poor (read slow)

Comment: I have explained what is wrong with your regex in my answer and provided some more information/demos.

Comment: *How* are you applying it to a stream?  Why don't you use `java.util.Scanner` and its `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` methods?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match then use this regex:

```
(.+?)(?:[\r\n]|$)
```

`(?:[\r\n]|$)` will match a line end (`\r` or `\n`) OR end of input thus making sure last line is also matched.

However `stringsplit("[\\r\\n]+");` should be preferred way here.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ5kD0/2)

Answer (score 1):

**Why is your regex incorrect?**

The `(.*[\r\n]+|$)` contains 2 alternatives:

- `.*[\r\n]+` - zero or more characters other than newline sequences (see below) and then one or more linebreaks (CR or/and LF)
- `|` - or...
- `$` - end of string

So, you actually misplaced the grouping, here is how you wanted it to look like:

```
String p = "(.*(?:[\r\n]+|$))";
String x = "  This is a new line=?xxx\n Whats' \n up";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(p).matcher(x);
while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/8KtcmI)

**If you want to match *lines***, it is easier to use a `.` that is matching any character but newline and carriage return, and some more "vertical whitespace" characters:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+"); // for non-empty lines
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*"); // for empty lines as well
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/BNylW3):

```
String x = "  This is a new line=?xxx\n Whats' \n up";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(".+");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(x);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

See [what `.` actually does not match](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt):

- A newline (line feed) character ('\n'),
- A carriage-return character followed immediately by a newline character ("\r\n"),
- A standalone carriage-return character ('\r'),
- A next-line character ('\u0085'),
- A line-separator character ('\u2028'), or
- A paragraph-separator character ('\u2029).
- If `UNIX_LINES` mode is activated, then the only line terminators recognized are newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

Why go this route when there's support out of the box in [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(^.+$)+", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher("This is a new line=?xxx\n Whats' \n up");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the input using a *reluctant* quantifier.

Try this regex:

```
"(?m).*$"
```

The `(?m)` flag makes `$` match every end of line (platform-independently), and dot still won't match newlines (so no need for reluctant quantifier). Use `m.group(0)` or just `m.group()`.

---

To match non-empty sentences, use a "+":

```
"(?m).+$"
```

To match non-blank (at least 1 non-whitespace):

```
"(?m).*\\S.*$"
```

See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/aK1uS8/1).

Comment: Is there a way to ignore empty spaces?

Comment: These regexes will work, but the reluctant quantifiers are irrelevant.

Comment: @alan you are so right! Thanks for noticing - updated. (I started off without `(?m)`, and it didn't occur to me that non greedy was no longer required with `(?m)`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Pattern.compile("(.+[\r\n]?+)");
```

It worked for me.